# VBA Excel value rounds when paste in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new in vba. I need to paste value to cell using Macros. When I paste value to cell it's rounds. For example I have value 5.048 and when I paste it into cell value rounds to 5.05 but I need 5.048 there. I use this code:

```
Range(Cell1, Cell1).Value = Replace(CStr(sum), ",", ".")
```

And if I do so:

```
Range(Cell1, Cell1).Value =Replace(CStr(Round(sum, 3)), ",", ".")
```

Result is the same. How can I format cell to display 3 digits after decimal point?

Comment: Use `Range(Cell1, Cell1).NumberFormat` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams If I use Range(Cell1, Cell1).NumberFormat = "#,###0.000" that's just put #### to cells

Comment: Widen the column in order to display all of the displayed digits within the formatted cell.

Comment: @Jeeped Thank you, that's my fault. Everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range(Cell1, Cell1).Value = Replace(CStr(Sum), ",", ".")
Range(Cell1, Cell1).NumberFormat = "0.000"
```

"0.000" = Three decimals. Increase the amount of zeros if you want more decimals.